# In ag-grid react, how do we do server side pagination with real server api call?

Tags: pagination, ag-grid, server-side-rendering, ag-grid-react

In ag-grid react, how do we do server side pagination with real server api call ? how does the grid know about the remaining count for pagination to show next page button?

I don't know how to tell datagrid about the total rows. I have 100 rows in server. I am only sending first 10 to the grid. How do I tell the grid that there are remaining 90?

Comment: you can send `total_count` of rows with data